# How to change the background or a color of DIV using jQuery colorpicker?

Tags: jquery

can you please help, i am using this colorpicker here: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

and i don't know how to use it, for example if i would like to change the site background color, or a color of Div element, or the color of text how it can be done?

here is the live example... http://pastehtml.com/view/1e78noi.html

for example how would like to change background color, and the color of slider-bg DIV and the color of text DIV.

Please use this site: pastehtml.com to purplish your Live and working html code for showing to me. and copy the sources URL scripts from my source file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to use the onchange event the [colorpicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) provides:

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
       //this is what you need
       $(".text").css("color", "#" + hex);
    }
});
```

working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/r9ZeA/

Comment: Where shall i paste the code you have provided, can you please provide me the complete working code, because i am quite new with jquery, i will really appreciate it. you can see my source code here: http://pastehtml.com/view/1e78noi.html  and you can publish your working online code here using this service: http://pastehtml.com Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks! now how do change the color of full body background of my website, can you provide me working sample of that too please!

Comment: You can use jQuery to manipulate the css of every element on a page. For changing the body color you would need  $("body").css("background", "#" + hex); Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9ZeA/1/ It might be helpfull to look at the jquery documentation of .css() function: http://api.jquery.com/css/